# "For loop" is working for the first variable and not for the rest of the variables in python

Tags: python, for-loop

Why "for loop" is working for the first variable and not for the rest of the variables? I have tried the below python code for outliers:

```
def outliers(features, df):
    for i in features:
        Q1=df[i].quantile(0.25)
        Q3=df[i].quantile(0.75)
        IQR=Q3-Q1
        upper=Q3+(1.5*IQR)
        lower=Q1-(1.5*IQR)
        df.loc[(df[i]>upper),i] = upper 
        df.loc[(df[i]<lower),i] = lower
        return i

outliers(['Infant_Deaths','Hepatitis', 'Measles', 'Underfive_Deaths', 'Polio', 'Diphtheria', 
          'HIV', 'GDP', 'Population','Malnourished10_19','Malnourished5_9', 'Income_Index', 'Schooling'], df)
```

Answer (score 1):

Remove the `return` statement from your for loop. `return` will cause you to exit the function (and for loop)!

```
def outliers(features, df): 
    for i in features: 
        Q1=df[i].quantile(0.25) 
        Q3=df[i].quantile(0.75) 
        IQR=Q3-Q1 
        upper=Q3+(1.5IQR) 
        lower=Q1-(1.5IQR) 
        df.loc[(df[i]>upper),i] = upper 
        df.loc[(df[i]<lower),i] = lower

outliers(['Infant_Deaths','Hepatitis', 'Measles', 'Underfive_Deaths', 'Polio', 'Diphtheria', 'HIV', 'GDP', 'Population','Malnourished10_19','Malnourished5_9', 'Income_Index', 'Schooling'], df)
```

Comment: Does `df` update from inside method? You may want to `return df` outside loop at the end and call by assignment `new_df = outliers(...)`.

Comment: @Parfait AFAIK df is a mutable type and will be updated inside the method.

Comment: True but always good practice in functional programming to `return` and assign (`=`) new objects. This avoid side effects which become hard to debug. O/w OP does not need a method.

Comment: def outliers(features, df):
    for i in features:
        Q1=df[i].quantile(0.25)
        Q3=df[i].quantile(0.75)
        IQR=Q3-Q1
        upper=Q3+(1.5*IQR)
        lower=Q1-(1.5*IQR)
        df.loc[(df[i]>upper),i] = upper 
        df.loc[(df[i]<lower),i] = lower
        df_outliers=outliers(['Infant_Deaths','Measles', 'Underfive_Deaths', 
          'HIV', 'GDP', 'Population','Malnourished10_19','Malnourished5_9', 'Income_Index'], df)
        return df   This works :-)

Comment: @Parfait, still this code does not help in replacing the outliers completely. Could you help me with what went wrong

Comment: How are you calling this method? Be sure the `return` is not indented inside `for` loop.